# c# Regex for file extension embedded in a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to extract file extension that is embedded in a connection string. I was wondering if it's possible to achieve it using `Regex`? or any solution would be of great help. The `connection string` looks something similar to this:

```
"Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Extended
 Properties=&quot;DSN=Excel Files; DBQ=&lt;Assume_Location&gt;FILE_NAME.xls;
DriverId=1046;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;&quot;"
```

In this example the filename is of extension ".xls" but this can be anything e.g. xlsx, dbf, mdb, accdb etc. . We don't have control over how the connection string is generated

Data Source (i.e. DBQ in this example) may be different for different connection strings e.g. Network Address, SourceDB, Server, Hostname etc.

Comment: When you get the connection string from code, I'll say that the `&quot;` will be changed to `"`, right?

Comment: We cannot rely on DriverId. Data Source (i.e. DBQ in this case) can be different also (e.g. Network Address, HostName, SourceDB, Server, Hostname)

Comment: @xanatos that's correct.

Comment: So how should a human recognize a filename? Just because it has a `.` and an extension of three characters? You know that newer excel files have an extension of 4 characters? (xlsx)... so even the length of the extension isn't a good way to distinguish random `.` from "extension" `.`

Comment: @xanatos thanks for your input. You are right, the extension is not limited to xls and can be of different types and lengths. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work assuming:

- The file name does not contain `;`
- There is a period between the filename and the extension
- There is a `;` before the filename
- There is a `;` after the extension

  ```
  string pattern = @";(?<filename>[^;]*)[.]{1,1}.*;";
  string fileName = Regex.Match(connectionString, pattern).Groups["filename"].Value;
  ```

Or if this `<Assume_Location>`  is before the file name rather than `;` then you can use this for the pattern:

```
string pattern = @"<Assume_Location>(?<filename>[^;]*)[.]{1,1}.*;";
```

## Edit 1 - In response to comment.

One of these should work if you need the extension as well:

```
string pattern = @";(?<filename>[^;]*[.]{1,1}[^;]*);";
string pattern = @"<Assume_Location>(?<filename>[^;]*[.]{1,1}[^;]*);";
```

## Edit 2 - In response to more comments.

This should absolutely work (unless it does not, then I will edit this to tone down the confidence level).

```
string pattern = @";[^=]*=<[^>]*>(?<filename>[^;]*[.][^;]*);";
```

or this if `&gt;` and `&lt;` is not replaced with angle brackets:

```
string pattern = @";[^=]*=&lt;.*&gt;(?<filename>[^;]*[.][^;]*);";
```

Comment: thanks Jason. this is pretty close but this returns only the FILE_NAME. would it be possible to include extension as well?

Comment: Updated my answer to include patterns that will get the file name and extension.

Comment: the issue with the connection string is that <Assume_Location> may not always be there. So this is something we cannot always rely upon.

Comment: Well, we have to have some bit of string that we can rely on to always be there to use as an anchor to start searching from.  Is it safe to say that `FILE_NAME` will always be preceded by `;` or `;<Assume_Location>`? I may be able to do something with that.

Comment: Oops, rather, will `FILE_NAME` be preceded by `;` or `;DBQ=<Assume_Location>`?

Comment: FILE_NAME preceded by ; (YES) But <Assume_Location> is just a parameter and the person generating this connection string may name it something else e.g <Some_Location>. DBQ is a data source name and can be different too as I mentioned in my edited question. Cheers!

Comment: That makes it tough.  Then all we can really search for is any string between two `;` that contains at least one `.`.  There is no guarantee that we will get a single hit with a search like that.

Comment: Okay, so the data source name can be different but will it always be there?  Can I rely on something like this `;DATA_SOURCE_NAME=<LOCATION>FILE_NAME.EXT;` where everything in caps will be in the string it just will not necessarily have a constant value?

Comment: Thanks Jason, I appreciate your effort but this time it doesn't return a match. Regards!

Comment: Can you give me the string that it is not matching on.

Comment: I tried matching the pattern on the string posted in my original question

Comment: The regex I have assumed that `&gt;` and `&lt;` would be changed to `<` and `>` respectively before being operated on.  Is that not the case?

Comment: sorry, you were right. this works now. great! Thanks for your help

Comment: Whew, I was running out of steam.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not 100% sure, but it seems like the file is the only thing that is not assigned, is it? Then you can use the following (not tested):

```
(;|^)(?<File>[^=]+)(;|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the filename always starts with `<Assume_Location>` then you can:

```
public static string GetAssumeLocation(string connectionString)
{
    const string assumeLocation = "<Assume_Location>";

    var builder1 = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder1.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    object extended;

    if (builder1.TryGetValue("Extended Properties", out extended) && extended is string)
    {
        var builder2 = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder2.ConnectionString = (string)extended;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kv in builder2)
        {
            var value = kv.Value as string;

            if (value != null && value.StartsWith(assumeLocation))
            {
                return Path.GetExtension(value.Substring(assumeLocation.Length));
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Note that I'm using the `DbConnectionStringBuilder` to "split" the connection string, and I'm looking only in the `Extended Properties`.